# How to test Xcode (Swift) playgrounds in Travis CI

Tags: swift, xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci, swift-playground

Travis CI [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/) describes the process of setting up the continuous integration for Swift applications. However, only the Xcode **projects** are mentioned where the `xcode_project` and `xcode_scheme` configuration keys are required.

Is there any standard way to test Xcode Swift **playgrounds** in Travis CI?

If no, what `script` should be written in order to run such test?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Is there any standard way to test Xcode Swift playgrounds in Travis CI?" 

Do you want to compile them? run them? or run test cases against them?

Comment: @OliverAtkinson I want to run a `XCTestCase` located in one of the `.swift` files.

Comment: https://flight.school/articles/running-xcode-playgrounds-on-travis-ci/ ?